# How to efficiently apply a function to each DataFrame of a Pandas Panel

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a function to every DataFrame in a Pandas Panel. I can write it as a loop but the indexing seems to take a long time. I am hoping a builtin Pandas function might be faster.

I have data frames which look like (in reality about 50 rows per column):

```
mydata = pd.DataFrame( { 'hits' : [ 123, 456,678 ], 'sqerr' : [ 253, 641, 3480] } )
```

They are arranged in a panel with a multi-index key:

```
mydict = { (0, 20 ) : mydata, (30, 40 ) : moredata }
mypanel = pd.Panel( mydict )
```

The panel looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 1600 (items) x 48 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: (-4000, -4000) to (3800, 3800)
Major_axis axis: 0 to 47
Minor_axis axis: hits to sqerr
```

I have a function which takes a DataFrame and outputs a number:

```
def condenser( df ):
    return some_stuff( df['hits'], df['sqerr'] )
```

I want to reduce my Panel to a Series, indexed by my multi-index and with results of my condenser function as its values.

I can do:

```
intermediate = []
for k, df in mypanel.iteritems():
    intermediate.append( condenser( df ) )

result = pd.Series( results, index = pypanel.items )
```

which gives the required result, but when I profile it, only 4% of the time is spent in my `condenser` function. Most of the time is spent in `iteritems` and `__getitem__` so I wondered if it could be done better.

I looked at `mypanel.apply( condenser, axis = 'items' )` but this loops over each column of my DataFrames separately. Is there something which would apply a function to each DataFrame?

P.s. I am using Python 2.7.9 and pandas 0.15.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply is correct, but the usage is:

mypanel.apply(condenser, axis=[1,2])

This will pass a 48 x 2 DataFrame into condenser.

Comment: I had to explicitly convert the return value of `condenser` to float but then it worked perfectly.